# Is it valid to initialize an instance of a class within the same class?

Tags: object-oriented, class-design, class

I was wondering if it's valid to initialize an instance of a class within the same class? For example:

```
public class Person()
{ 
   string name;
   string age;
   public Person getPerson()
   { 
       Person p1=new Person();
       //some logic here
       return p1
    }
}
```

I ended up doing that for a part of my code at work and thus wanted to know if there are any potential problems with doing something like this.

Comment: When the instance returned by getPerson is not influenced by the Person instance you call it on, the function should be declared and called static.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is valid.

That's called a factory method.

The [**Calendar**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, for example has a `getInstance()` method.

That's also useful when implementing the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

[Here you have a SO question about when to use a factory method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849/factory-pattern-when-to-use-factory-methods)

Comment: [Obligatory beware of using the singleton pattern link](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/).

Comment: Should be noted that for a factory, `getPerson()` should be static.

Comment: If it is not static, and it copies data from the current instance to the new instance, it is a clone method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Often done when you need to build large, dynamic, self-maintaining structures like Trees:

```
class Tree {

  public IComparable Value;
  private Tree Left;
  private Tree Right;

  public Add (IComparable value) {
    if (this.Value == null) {
      this.Value = value;

      // RIGHT HERE!
      this.Left = new Tree();
      this.Right = new Tree();

    } else {
      if (value > this.Value) {
        this.Right.Add(value);
      } else {
        this.Left.Add(value);
      }
    }
  } // Add()

} // class Tree
```